# Element inside Ajax pop up(buttons) in seleinum not able to find?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, getelementbyid

I need to select the element inside the popup in selenium webdriver.THis element inside the div  call as ajax popup pleae help me?

```
<a class="modalCloseImg simplemodal-close" title="Close"></a>
<div class="simplemodal-wrap" tabindex="-1" style="height: 100%; outline: 0px none; width: 100%; overflow: auto;">
    <div id="ajaxcart" class="ajaxcart simplemodal-data" style="">
        <p class="popup-success-msg"></p>
        <div class="popup-content"></div>
        <div class="ajaxcart-buttons-container">
            <a class="simplemodal-close btn-small-dark-grey"></a>
            <a class="ajaxcart-btn btn-small-orange" href="http://www.xcite.com"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which element are you talking about ? `<a class="ajaxcart-btn btn-small-orange" href="http://www.xcite.com"></a>` or `<a class="simplemodal-close btn-small-dark-grey"></a>`

Comment: this element<a class="ajaxcart-btn btn-small-orange" href="http://www.xcite.com"></a>, this is inside the ajax popup.